# ¿Como comparar dos datetime usando js?

Tags: javascript

¿como puedo comparar 2 date times?, ejemplo : '2017-12-06 15:00' y '2017-12-06 14:00' para usarlo en una condicional.

este es mi código:

```
var inicio  = '2017-12-06 15:00';
var termino = '2017-12-06 14:00';

if(inicio > termino){
  alert("Error!");
};
```

Pero la comparación no la hace correctamente.

Comment: Para el trato de fechas en Javascript, recomiendo la librería https://momentjs.com/ Te salva la vida.

Comment: Gracias amigo esto me funciono!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tardes, ya encontré una solución usando la librería moment.js gracias a un comentario de un usuario, les dejo el código de como lo solucione

```
function compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB) {
    var momentA = moment(dateTimeA,"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
    var momentB = moment(dateTimeB,"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");
    if (momentA > momentB) return 1;
    else if (momentA < momentB) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

alert(compare("2017-12-06 13:00", "2017-12-06 14:00"));
```

desde ya muchas gracias a todos por contribuir a la solución, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa con `JavaScript`, convertir en entero los datos y compararlos numéricamente, como su formato de fecha son iguales y las horas son en 24H puede funcionar:

```js
var inicio  = '2016-12-06 13:00';
var termino = '2017-11-06 14:00';

//quita (-),(:), espacios y los comvierte en entero
inicio = parseInt(inicio.replace(/-|:|\s/g , ""));
termino = parseInt(termino.replace(/-|:|\s/g , ""));

//compara que dato es mayor
if(inicio > termino){
  alert("inicio mayor que termino");
}else{
  alert("termino mayor que inicio");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar dos fechas debemos tener en cuenta en primer lugar que los objetos sean de **tipo Date**.

```
var f1 = new Date(2017, 12, 31);
var f2 = new Date(2018, 1, 1);
```

Podrás usar los siguientes operadores perfectamente, solo encontraras problemas con el operador `==`

```
>
<
>=
<=
```

Si ejecutamos la siguiente comparación, estamos comprobando que ambos objetos sean iguales lo cual es falso.

```
if(f1 == f2){
   return true;
}
```

Para comprobar si ambas fechas son iguales debemos usar el metodo `.getTime()`

```
if(f1.getTime() == f2.getTime()){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Te comprendo pero son 2 campos con formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm como uso este código para compararlos con ese formato?

Answer (score 0):

De entrada, tu tienes dos string en formato de fecha. Primero debes de crear dos elementos date, y después realizar la comparación entre fechas.

```js
function CompararFechas()
{
 //Comprobamos que tenga formato correcto
 var fecha_aux = document.getElementById("Fecha").value.split("-");
  var Fecha1 = new Date(parseInt(fecha_aux[2]),parseInt(fecha_aux[1]-1),parseInt(fecha_aux[0]));
 
  //Comprobamos si existe la fecha
 if (isNaN(Fecha1)){
  alert("Fecha introducida incorrecta");
  return false;
 }
 else{
  alert("La fecha que has introducido es "+Fecha1);
 }
}
//var inicio  = '2017-12-06 15:00';
//var termino = '2017-12-06 14:00';
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Comparacion Fechas JS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Introduce Fecha:</th>
                    <th><input id="Fecha" type="text" /></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="CompararFechas()"/></th>
                </tr>
            </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Ya que ten tienes listo tu fecha, ahora si se realiza la comparación entre fechas. Puedes hacerlo entre cada elemento o la fecha completa con la funcion de
**getTime()** para obtener el valor aritmético de las fechas.

```js
function CompararFechas()
{
 //Comprobamos que tenga formato correcto
 var fecha_aux = document.getElementById("Fecha").value.split("-");
  var Fecha1 = new Date(parseInt(fecha_aux[2]),parseInt(fecha_aux[1]-1),parseInt(fecha_aux[0]));
  var fecha_aux2 = document.getElementById("Fecha").value.split("-");
  var Fecha2 = new Date(parseInt(fecha_aux2[2]),parseInt(fecha_aux2[1]-1),parseInt(fecha_aux2[0]));
  //Comprobamos si existe la fecha
 if (isNaN(Fecha1)){
  alert("Fecha introducida incorrecta");
  return false;
 }
 else{
  alert("La fecha que has introducido es "+Fecha1);
 }
  
  if(Fecha1.getTime() == Fecha2.getTime()){
    alert("Ambas fechas son iguales");
}
  
var AnyoFecha = Fecha1.getFullYear();
var MesFecha = Fecha1.getMonth();
var DiaFecha = Fecha1.getDay();
 
var AnyoHoy = Fecha2.getFullYear();
var MesHoy = Fecha2.getMonth();
var DiaHoy = Fecha2.getDay();
 
if (AnyoFecha < AnyoHoy){
    alert ("La fecha introducida es anterior a Hoy");
}
else{
    if (AnyoFecha == AnyoHoy && MesFecha < MesHoy){
        alert ("La fecha introducida es anterior a Hoy");   
    }
    else{
        if (AnyoFecha == AnyoHoy && MesFecha == MesHoy && DiaFecha < DiaHoy){
            alert ("La fecha introducida es anterior a Hoy");
        }
        else{
            if (AnyoFecha == AnyoHoy && MesFecha == MesHoy && DiaFecha == DiaHoy){
                 alert ("Has introducido la fecha de Hoy");
            }
            else{
                alert ("La fecha introducida es posterior a Hoy");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Comparacion Fechas JS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Introduce Fecha:</th>
                    <th><input id="Fecha" type="text" /></th>
                    <th><input id="Fecha2" type="text" /></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="CompararFechas()"/></th>
                </tr>
            </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```